# Disabling CSRF in my web app or a safer approach

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm creating a web app in Laravel, but `CSRF` is killing its ajax functionality.

The submission of the token with ajax works fine, using `ajaxSetup` I can attach the token to every request, so no problem with this part.

But every time the user leaves the browser window for too long (perhaps a couple hours or more) ajax requests start returning `error 500` (token mismatch) - perhaps the server updates the token and the client keeps the old one, forcing the user to refresh the page to keep it functional, something I don't want to do.

So I was thinking of creating some sort of ajax timer to get the updated `csrf` token from the server every once in a while.. but it seems a bit of a hackish solution, and maybe even useless? (if I'm serving the token, someone can request it and still do a csrf attack, right?)

To solve this issue once and for all, I would have to do something more risky, disabling `CSRF` completely for ajax calls. My question is: Could this really hurt my security that bad? I've seen many people recommending to turn it off, but it seems like a big deal if someone can cross-request sensitive actions on a user account (such as delete account or something like this)

What would you guys recommend? This issue is keeping me awake a night :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only on option in mind for now...

You can start looking at CORS configurations on your application.

Changing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers for few `routes`. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: Sounds interesting @Alvaro Joao I've been researching this and it seems like a safe alternative! Valeu :)